# Gtk Paned on both Gtk HeaderBar and Window

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I'm trying to make a code editor (like gedit) in Python + Gtk3. On gedit there is a handle for the files view that is extended to the headerbar, any idea how to make something like that? 
Check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xR0L.png) to see what I mean.

Comment: If you want to know how they do it in gedit, read the gedit source code!

Comment: Hi Paulo, welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry you didn't find it useful, but it's quite common to use comments to give a pointer to where someone can find out an answer for themselves. If I were going to answer this question, I would indeed look it up directly in the gedit source code. (But I'm not, because you can look it up as easily as I can, and at the same time you will learn how to answer future similar questions for yourself.)

Comment: I was rude sry, I did try searching on gedit's source but it is all written in C, even tho I know C it is a lot more complicated to find it, I was hoping that someone knew how to do it in Python.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah, that I can help with. Check [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gedit/blob/9a7f1542ce0fa5ddc23fc60c5848a80dd80bd8eb/gedit/resources/ui/gedit-window.ui#L9), [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gedit/blob/9a7f1542ce0fa5ddc23fc60c5848a80dd80bd8eb/gedit/resources/ui/gedit-window.ui#L137), and [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gedit/blob/9a7f1542ce0fa5ddc23fc60c5848a80dd80bd8eb/gedit/resources/ui/gedit-window.ui#L11). Also you can launch applications with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` to poke around in them.

Comment: Wow that helped a lot, I didn't realize they used .ui files for designing the window, that's why I didn't find it in the code. I read a word "sync" on that file, and that gave me an idea when the handle in the GtkPaned on the header bar is moved, I'll manually move the bottom one as well. Thanks. PS I knew about the GTK_DEBUG thing :)